# Why doesn't JQuery .hide() function work with bootstrap spinner?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, spinner

I am doing a simple spinner feedback while my server answers an ajax query. I call the JQuery `.show()` function before making the ajax call and have the `.hide()` function called in the `.always()` callback of the request.

But my spinner never hides ! I don't understand why... has anybody encountered this problem using the `.hide()` function of JQuery with a Bootstrap spinner ?

More info on `.getJSON()` [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), more info on the `.hide()` and `.show()` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp).

This is my html spinner, it commes from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/spinners/)

```html
<div id="spinner-map-right-click" class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my javascript :

```
$('#spinner-map-right-click').show()
$.getJSON({ url: "myurl" })
    .done(function(data) {
        // does stuff here and it works
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        // display error message if there is an error
    })
    .always(function(data) {
        console.log("Hiding")
        // the console log displays but my spinner is always ther :(
        $('#spinner-map-right-click').hide()
    });
```

The request works, I get the data correctly and `"Hiding"` is displayed correctly so the `always()` callback is correctly called and when I inspect the code from Firefix I see the `<div>` has been correctly modified :

```html
<div id="spinner-map-right-click" class="d-flex justify-content-center" style="display: none;">
    <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of `d-flex` class. You can try

```
$('#spinner-map-right-click').addClass('d-none') // removeClass('d-none')
```

`d-flex` by bootstrap using [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) exception which override `inline` style

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. It's only happening for the class `d-flex`. **Because this class is containing a property `display: flex !important;`. Because of presence of `!important` exception, `display: none;` is not working** (N.B. When you use .hide(), it assign `display: none;` to the element). That's why I removed the class `d-flex` and gave the element following style without `!important` exception. And now it's working.

```
#spinner-map-right-click {
  display: flex;
}
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/dev-showrin/pen/gNQaOK)

Comment: Your solution works great thanks ! But i don't understand the Codepen link.

Comment: @PercevalDev I am extremely sorry for my mistake. Actually I sent you a wrong link. I just fixed it. Now you can check it.