# jquery .show does not make a hidden div visible

Tags: jquery

i have a multiselect box which is hidden by default,i want to show it  when the codition which i shown below is meet,it meets the condition but does not show it,where i am wrong?

```
  <div><select id="fltBydisc" class="hidden ></select></div>
```

css for hide it:

```
 .hidden{ visibility:hidden }
```

i have a condition to show it:

```
 if (is_Mbox === true ) {                          
      $("#fltBydisc").show();
           }
```

is_mbox is true and it reaches the .show() part,but does not show anything!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't JQuery .hide() function work with bootstrap spinner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57018812/why-doesnt-jquery-hide-function-work-with-bootstrap-spinner) -- the answer is right in this question, which got asked earlier today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) instead passing your boolean in as second argument

```
$("#fltBydisc").toggleClass('hidden', !is_Mbox);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `class="hidden"` try using `style="display: none;"`.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.show adds `display: block` and jQuery.hide adds `display:none`.

If want to show that hidden div call  `$("#fltBydisc").removeClass('hidden')`

and to hide it again `$("#fltBydisc").addClass('hidden')`